# Is it possible to post to Twitter attaching the latitude and longitude to the tweet?

Tags: c#, .net, twitter

We run an ASP.NET MVC application, and want it to post geolocalized tweets to Twitter, is it possible?
I know there are some c# APIs to post to Twitter, but i really don't know if they allow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The [POST status documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update) is very clear

As well as POSTing the status message, you can also include lat & long.

That's it at its most basic.  How you actually authenticate & do the HTTP request depends on the framework you choose.